# No Resource found that matches given name error(AppCompat_v7) in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I tried creating an Android activity with Action Bar in Eclipse. I ended up in facing some error in appcompat_7 dependency.

And the error was **No resource found that matches the given name** on item tag under style

[image]

and its corresponding error is

[image]

Someone help me to get out of this.

Comment: I tried cleaning the project and build again, but still no result

Comment: what is your adt version? (sdk.buildtools in your project.properties ?)

Comment: @e4c5 My ADT package version is 23.0.2.1259578.

Comment: Are you using API 23 to compile?

Comment: No i tried compile with API level 22

Comment: What worked for me was 21.1.2  (not this exact resource error but there were plenty of others)